# In bootstrap 4 nav bar after adding container the contents automatically aligns right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hello I am new to bootstrap so I apologize if this question is too naive. I am trying to make a navbar using bootstrap but after adding container class inside nav tags the logo stays left but the links aligns right. I want the links to stay beside the logo on the right side and only sign in and sign up to align right. The code I wrote is below
[And this is the image of the navbar where the links are automatically aligned to right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONFXJ.png)

```
<nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-expand-md py-0">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bird.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:40px;">
        </a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Subscriptions</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign In</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some code i hava add please have a look and you can see the snippet on full screen to see the result.

```html
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-expand-md py-0">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bird.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:40px;">
        </a>
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
     <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Subscriptions</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign In</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
  </div>
     </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The signup and sign-in are aligned to right with the code below. Add class `signup` and `signin` class to the respective `nav-item` HTML code. Then, add in the CSS code.

```
<li class="nav-item signup">
<li class="nav-item signin">
```

```css
.nav-item.signup {
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
}

.nav-item.signin {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .nav-item.signup,
  .nav-item.signin {
    position: unset;
    right: unset;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-expand-md py-0">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bird.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:40px;">
  </a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Subscriptions</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item signup">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item signin">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign In</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```